# VBA Evaluate function and array formula returning range of values

Tags: vba, excel

Suppose I want to use Evaluate function to evaluate an array formula which returns a range of values. For example I try to get index (using Excel function MATCH) in an ordered list in Sheet2!A:A for each values in Sheet1!A:A. And I want to put the indices in column B.

```
Dim sh as Worksheet
Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
sh.Range("B1:B10").Value = sh.Evaluate("=MATCH(A1:A10,Sheet2!A:A)")
```

Whan I run the code, I get a column of repeated values - the values are equal to the index of the first element. This is not correct.

When I try the same by putting array formula in the worksheet {=MATCH(A1:A10,Sheet2!A:A)}, it works without problems and returns the correct index for every element.

So my question: how to use Evaluate function returning a whole range of values?

Comment: Try `Evaluate("=TRANSPOSE(MATCH(A1:A10,Sheet2!A:A))")` or `Application.Transpose(Evaluate("=MATCH(A1:A10,Sheet2!A:A)"))`

Comment: No, that does not work either - I tested it. I would be surprised if it worked because A1:A10 is a column of source values and B1:B10 is also a column. Transpose should not be necessary, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting issue.  I was not able to get the MATCH function to return an array using VBA Evaluate.  However, the following modification seems to work, using the zero (0) for the row argument in the index function returns all of the rows.  Note also that I added the match_type argument to the Match function.

```
sh.Range("B1:B10").Value = sh.Evaluate("=INDEX(MATCH(A1:A10,Sheet2!A:A,0),0,1)")
```

Comment: You always need to force a function that is not naturally an array formula when using Evaluate, as you did here. Note you can simply use INDEX(function,) without any explicit parameters) or an IF(ROW(range),function) construct.

Comment: @rory You should add that as an answer. Deserves more attention and a bounty.

Answer (score 2):

If *Evaluate()* does not make you happy, then:

```
Sub marine()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, r As Range
    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set r = sh.Range("B1:B10")
    r.FormulaArray = "=MATCH(A$1:A$10,Sheet2!A:A,0)"
    r.Copy
    r.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```