# Evaluate formula not working in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, match

What is the wrong with the following formula ?

```
matchformula = "{=MATCH(1, (G12= G:G) , 0)}"
x = MySheet.Evaluate(matchformula)
```

Whereas the code below yields a correct result.

```
matchformula = "=MATCH(G12, G:G , 0)"
x = MySheet.Evaluate(matchformula)
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27669551/4996248 . There seems to be some issues with using `Evaluate` with array formulas. The accepted answer gives a work-around.

Comment: Nope, this does not work for me either. My final goal is to come up with a match containing multiple criteria. I have blown my mind trying to do this !!!!

Comment: You are in luck..............I believe **VBA** will evaluate all formulas as if they were array formulas!!

Comment: It really isn't clear what your formula is trying to do -- find the indices of everything equal to 1 in column G, but only if G12 is 1?

Comment: I believe your first formula will always return `#N/A`.  `Lookup_array` returns an array of `{TRUE,FALSE,...}`, `Lookup_value` is 1, so you will never see an exact match.  Also, the curly brackets you have included in your string are not really a part of the formula, as they never get typed in when you enter the formula on a worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

**VBA** should handle this automatically.  Consider this array formula case:

[image]

In **VBA** the equivalent code gives the same results:

```
Sub qwerty()
MsgBox Evaluate("MIN(IF(A1:A3>2,A1:A3))")
End Sub
```

There is no need to tell **VBA** that the formula should be treated as an array formula.